# Bootstrap Grid System Not Having Desired Effect

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

I recently started using Bootstrap on an old Rails project. I'm using the grid system to align the main content and the sidebar. Below is a code snippet from a file (index.html.erb) in my "view" folder.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8"> 
              <div id="featured_gallery" class="wide_content_box rounded_border">
                <%= content_tag :div do %>
                <%= content_tag :span, :class => "results_head" do %>
                <%= _('Featured gallery') %>: <%= link_to(truncate(h(@featured_gallery.name), :length => 30), @featured_gallery) %>
                <% end -%>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= more_link(galleries_path(:filter => 'featured')) %>
                <% end %>
                <%= render :partial => "projects/project", :collection => @featured_gallery_projects %>
                <div class="clear">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="greeting">
                    <div id="hi">
                        <%= user_thumbnail(current_user, :thumb_tiny) %><%= random_hi %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="clear">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Instead of aligning the two parts side-by-side, this has the following effect. I'm unable to understand why, and would appreciate any insight to get it aligned properly. The who's online, featured and other parts are supposed to appear on top of each other in a column to the right of the main content.

[image]

**EDIT:** My divs are correctly nested. Just for testing, I created another row above my original using the following code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            First column!
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            "Second column"
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            Third column!
        </div>
    </div>
```

This, too, results in the 3 comments stacking on top of each other (instead of being 3 different columns in the same row), which is far from expected. This is extremely strange, since as far as I know, I am following the instructions of the grid system implementation. Thoughts?

**Note:** My code has the desired effect on Bootply, but is not working for the web project that I am working on.

**PS:** I installed bootstrap via a gem, which added bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less to my stylesheets. However, my application.css has no mention of bootstrap (It does not 'require' any bootstrap css file. I did not change it since installing the gem was supposed to completely take care of that. Am I missing something? Is application.css supposed to require bootstrap for anything related to bootstrap to work?

Comment: The col-md-4 div is not inside the row div.

Comment: I adjusted it, indenting everything correctly and ensuring that the divs were correctly nested. It still doesn't work as desired.

Comment: @user3694391 which gem are you using? if you are using [bootstrap-saas](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) then it requires you to import bootstrap in your application.css.scss

Comment: Can you make an example on http://www.bootply.com/ that exhibits this problem?

Comment: I'm using the gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'.

Comment: My code has the desired affect on bootply, but fails to work for the webpage/rails project I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that my project was originally using SASS, as opposed to LESS, which is required by the twitter-bootstrap-gem. I have now switched to using the bootstrap sass gem, and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure divs are correctly nested

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8"> 
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More info: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid